# How to call Javascript function from Kotlin code?

Tags: javascript, compilation, kotlin

I am trying to compile Kotlin code as Javascript. In my code I need to encode string as URI. My 2 variants are both fail compilation:

```
class PlaceholderJS(prefix: String, placeholder: String?): Placeholder(prefix, placeholder) {
override fun encode(str: String): String {
    return encodeURIComponent(str)
}
```

In this code compiler cannot find function encodeURIComponent(str), which according to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp is supported by all browsers.

Alternative:

```
class PlaceholderJS(prefix: String, placeholder: String?): Placeholder(prefix, placeholder) {
override fun encode(str: String): String {
    return URLEncoder.encode(str, Charsets.UTF_8.name())
}
```

cannot find Java class URLEncoder (imported in the file as in Java). This works when compiled for JVM, but not JS.

Also I have Kotlin module marked with:

```
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.moduleKind = "umd"
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that latest way to declare Javascript function in Kotlin is:

```
external fun encodeURIComponent(str: String): String
```

Once added it to the Kotlin class everything get compiled without a problem.